From TeX inline math to LaTeX inline math
Many of you may have heard of LaTeX. Two sample LaTeX source files are the following ones:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  The sum $ \sum_{i = 1}^n i $ evaluates to $ n(n + 1)/2 $.
\end{document}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  The sum \( \sum_{i = 1}^n i \) evaluates to \( n(n + 1)/2 \).
\end{document}

As you can see, "mathy" text (like the summation symbol, which in (La)TeX is called \sum) has to be placed between two dollar signs or between a pair of \( and \) delimiters.
I strongly prefer the $s, but unfortunately there are people with opinions different than mines. So, it often happens to me that I have to convert my dollars-based math to parentheses-based math.
Based on this, some days ago I decided to roll up my sleeves and to dust off my C++ skills that were rotting in the back of my brain since high-school. This is the result:
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string latex2e_fy(const std::string& s_in) {
  bool d = false;

  std::string s_out;
  s_out.reserve(s_in.length());

  for(auto c : s_in) {
    if(c == '$' && d == false) {
      s_out.append("\\(");
      d = !d;
    }
    else if (c == '$' && d == true) {
      s_out.append("\\)");
      d = !d;
    }
    else {
      s_out.push_back(c);
    }
  }
  return s_out;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if(argc < 3) {
    std::cout << "Utilizzo: latex2e_fy input_file output_file." << "\n";

    return 1;
  }

  std::ifstream f_in(argv[1]);
  std::ofstream f_out(argv[2]);

  if(!f_in.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "Impossibile aprire "
              << argv[1] << "." << "\n"
              << "This is how I work: latex2e_fy input_file output_file." << "\n";

    return 1;
  }

  if(!f_out.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "Can't open "
              << argv[2] << "." << "\n"
              << "This is how I work: latex2e_fy input_file output_file." << "\n";

    return 1;
  }

  std::string current_line;

  while(std::getline(f_in,current_line)) {
    f_out << latex2e_fy(current_line) << "\n";
  }

  f_in.close();
  f_out.close();

  return 0;
}

As I anticipated, I learnt C++ (specifically, C++98) back in high-school, and my memories are starting to fade away. I'm also not that well-versed in programming in general, let alone in modern C++ standards and good practices. But I would like to become!
So now I'll let you speak. How good (bad?) is my code w.r.t. modern C++ standards and good programming practices?

What about display-mode math with $$ to \[ and \]? Dollar signs in expanded macros? Do you ever use \text or \ensuremath? You would need a much more complex parser to do this robustly.

The meaning of $ is context sensitive
You can't just replace every $ you encounter with \(/\), since the meaning of $ depends on the context it is in. Already Toby Speight pointed out that you need to handle the sequence \$ differently. But also consider the following:

Verbatim commands, like for example: \verb|$y = x^2$|
Verbatim environments, like:
\begin{verbatim}
$y = x^2$
\end{verbatim}


Comments, like: % $y = x^2$
Commands whose parameters are not treated like regular text, for example: \input{$.txt}

There might be other contexts in \$\LaTeX\$ where $ does not start or end an inline math environment.

Error messages should go to std::cerr rather than std::cout.
If we include <cstdlib> we have a useful macro EXIT_FAILURE which is more expressive than 1.
Is it essential that the program work with files, or would it be more useful if it can be a filter, reading from standard input, and writing to standard error?
Comparing a bool value against true or false is clunky - we can write d == true as simply d, and d == false as !d.
I'd probably restructure the loop to combine the two $ cases as
  for (auto c : s_in) {
    if (c == '$') {
      s_out.append(d ? "\\)" : "\\("));
      d = !d;
    } else {
      s_out.push_back(c);
    }
  }

It's probably a good idea to handle \$ differently, too.
It's not clear why we reset d at the start of each line.  I think that instead of reading lines into strings and converting each line as a free-standing unit, we should iterate through the entire input.  Using the Ranges library that arrived in C++20, we can create a view of the input:
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>

    auto iter = std::istream_iterator{f_in}, end = {};
    auto s_in = std::ranges::subrange(iter, end);


Toby, is checking whether the files were successfully open necessary? Won't the subsequent reading and writing throw an exception if opening the files failed?

Only if the stream was set to throw exceptions (in this code, that's neither of them).  Otherwise, we can just check the state of the stream via the usual conversion to bool.
